# I can't upload a multiple files to FTP by batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, automation

I can't succeed to upload a multiple files to some FTP by batch file I made.

Also, I want to upload all files from this local directory.

**The code:**

```
ftp -s:"C:\automation\fileup.bat" MYSERVER.COM
```

```
USERNAME
PASSWORD
ascii
cd "/public_html/reports/"
lcd "C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter"
mput *
close
quit
```

**The error:**

```
C:\automation>ftp -s:"C:\automation\fileup.bat" MYSERVER.COM
Connected to server26.000webhost.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 12 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 07:03. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
User (MYSERVER.COM:(none)):
331 User USERNAME OK. Password required

230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230-109 files used (1%) - authorized: 10000 files
230 14084 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 1536000 Kb
ftp> ascii
200 TYPE is now ASCII
ftp> cd "/public_html/reports/"
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/reports
ftp> lcd "C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter"
Local directory now C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter.
ftp> mput *
mput 000500de-0092-0095-00d9-00a100f000f7.json? close
mput 00090020-0041-007c-00db-00b9003c0085.json? quit
ftp>
```

**The files I've trying to upload:**

[image]

Comment: what's inside C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\ ? files, folders or maybe both?

and your code doesn't match the error log...

Comment: JSON , HTML & Image files @aronadaal

Comment: Actually, It doesn't upload the files to the FTP.
I don't know why it stuck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`prompt` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-prompt_1) to turn off transfer confirmation prompts:

> Toggles **prompt** mode on and off.

Without it, tje `ftp` uses the following commands in the script (the `close` and the `quit` in your case) as answers. As they are not `y`, the transfer is skipped.

---

Another option with the same effect is using the `-i` switch on the [`ftp` command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp):

> **-i** : Disables interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
ftp -i -s:"C:\automation\fileup.bat" MYSERVER.COM
```

And in your script, end it like this:

```
mput *  
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

FTP command allows sending multiple files but if we want directories and sub-directories auto created and transferred then alternatively, we can use **ncftp**. Steps below:

- Download **[NcFTP Client 3.2.6 for Microsoft Windows](http://www.ncftp.com/download/)** if you're using Windows PC for transferring files to Linux Server via FTP
- Since, you're trying to send via batch file, we can use **ncftpput** command which is Internet file transfer program for scripts
- Create batch file (say, ncftpupload.bat) and provide as:

Syntax:

```
ncftpput -u username -p password -m -R SERVER_IP_ADDRESS /remote_directory local_directory\*
```

Example:

```
ncftpput -u ftpuser1 -p ftppass1 -m -R 192.168.1.10 /var/www C:\public_html\*
```

The switches used are:

```
-u: FTP username
-p: FTP password
-m: Attempt to make the remote destination directory before copying.
-R: Recursive mode; copy whole directory trees
```