# copy files from ftp to local error

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I try to copy a lot of files from my ftp server `ftp://ftp.prodega.ch`, so I created a file called `code.txt` with this text:

```
open ftp.prodega.ch
user
password
lcd E:\f2      
cd Bilder1     
get file1.jpg
bye
```

Then I execute the following command in the command prompt:

```
ftp -s:code.txt
```

The file `file1.jpg` is copying into local `E:\f2` folder; I try to copy all files from the ftp folder `Bilder1` using `mget *` instead of `get file1.jpg` but it doesn't work.

The first image is copied successfully,  but the second image (using `mget *`) doesn't get copied and showed this result:

[image]

[image]

How would I be able to copy these files?

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work?" What should it be doing, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: You are welcome, consider upvoting [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30372138/850848) once you have enough reputation (15).

Comment: Also please accept the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering this command into your command prompt:

```
ftp -i -s:code.txt
```

Comment: right, this solved my problem, thank you!