# How do I copy txt files from a specific folder on an FTP site (which is password protected) to a local folder on my pc using a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I've been researching for hours now on how to to copy specific files from a folder on an FTP site, to a local folder on my PC.  Anytime I think I got something, I re-read it and get confused. Can someone spell it out for me on exactly how to accomplish the below scenario:

```
Dummy Info:
FTP Site:  ftp://ftp.johndoe.com
FTP UN:  John
FTP PW:  123
```

Folder on the FTP site that contains the files I want:

```
ftp://ftp.johndoe.com/Out
```

Items I wish to retrieve from this folder:  all `.txt` files
Then I need to copy it to:

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\FTP access Testing
```

Afterwards I need to delete everything in:

```
ftp://ftp.johndoe.com/Out
```

I would post code but I don't even know where to start.  Can someone please walk me through this?

Comment: Stack Overflow search with [\[batch-file\] copy all files ftp local](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+copy+all+files+ftp+local) returns a list with 15 results (not counting this one). [\[batch-file\] download all files ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+download+all+files+ftp) returns a list with 46 results. Other search terms are __[batch-file] download ftp directory__ and __[batch-file] download ftp folder__. Is there really absolutely nothing you can use from the found questions and answers?

Comment: @Mofi - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199888/copy-files-from-ftp-to-local-error this one is actually really close but how do I launch 'ftp - -s:code.txt' through the batch file?  Also, this looks like a file, what goes in it?

Comment: @Mofi If you can answer my last question I actually think that will work.

Comment: The link you posted, Jon, explains what goes into the file `code.txt`.  The way you launch a program in a batch file is the same way you'd type it from the command prompt.  So, create a batch file (such as `getfile.bat` and then put the `ftp` command in it.  Save it, and from the command prompt, type `getfile`.  If this doesn't answer your question -- then I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Steven K. Mariner Hi Steven, thank you for your response.  I'm trying to prevent having to do anything through the command prompt.  Basically, I need to be able to run this entire process through a Batch file.

Comment: I hooked up a `cmd` to `taskmgr` and I saw this: `Command Processor -> CMD.exe`. This means when you run a batch file, `CMD.exe` **must** start. If you want no command prompt, switch to Powershell/VBS/JScript...

Comment: Also, running all programs/scripts require a processor that can understand the code. If you run batch file, `CMD.EXE`. If you run Powershell, `POWERSHELL.EXE`. If you run VBS/JScript, `Cscript.exe` **or** `JScript.exe`.

Comment: It also seemed that you don't understand how batch file works, I'd recommend checking [here](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=how+batch+file+works&oq=how+batch+file+works&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.2181j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Please read this snippet from the page: `When a batch file is run, the shell program (usually COMMAND.COM or cmd.exe) reads the file and executes its commands, normally line-by-line. `. So, `CMD.EXE` must be started in order to read and execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this does not do everything you wanted, because you really should write this yourself.

But you asked for bread crumbs; an example of how to do this.

These three files could be used to set up a quick download -- but storing cleartext passwords is a bad idea.
A really bad idea.
A really, really bad idea.

Also, you'll need to consider if you should delete all files on the FTP site, or only those you've successfully downloaded.
That latter is far superior, but requires a fair investment of time to design a process which will give you some safety.
Good luck.

Anyway -- the download.  Three files follow.

The first one sets up the directories needed:

```
set-it-up.bat

@echo off
md "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\FTP access Testing\admin"
md "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\FTP access Testing\download"
```

The second one is a batch file to perform the download:

```
download.bat

@echo off
C:
cd "\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\FTP access Testing\download"
ftp -s ..\admin\doit_input_dl.txt ftp://ftp.johndoe.com
dir
```

The third one is the input file for the FTP process.

```
doit_input_dl.txt

John
123
prompt
ascii
cd /Out
mget *.txt
close
bye
```

If this doesn't give you enough information to round out the process, then you need to find someone who can code batch files.

Comment: This helps.  Thank you.